# Remove releases in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I have a problem with my releases in GitLab.

I created them in my project with tags. Now I want to remove them, so I deleted the associated tags but my releases are always displayed. I searched on Google and Stack Overflow but I can't find any solutions.

How can I remove these releases without their tags?

Comment: seems that currently when you delete a tag, the release is deleted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently (GitLab v11.9.8) **you can't**. It's silly, I know, but you can't.

Ivan came up with a workaround if you have only a few releases to delete. His steps are copied below.

> Ivan Kostrubin (@ovitente):
>
> For fixing this issue you have to go through those steps
>
> - Create tag with the same name and release message that was in release, you will be able to edit this tag.
> - Open tag's release message for editing
> - Remove all text
> - Save it
> - And release has gone from the release list.
> - Then you can freely delete tag.
>
> Source:
>   https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/58549#note_160000873

Check out these GitLab issues:

- [[#58549] Deleting releases with removed TAG in Release API](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/58549)
- [[#56026] Make it possible to add/edit/delete a release using the UI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26016)

Comment: This answer is outdated, this is a supported feature now. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63810511/1988326) from conurus

Comment: The answer from conurus only deletes the tag, not the release

Answer (score 41):

1. Go to Project Overview -> Releases
2. Click the release you want to delete
3. Scroll to the bottom. Find the tag icon. Click on the tag.
4. There is a trash can button for the tag. Deleting the tag will delete the release as well.

Comment: Deleting the tag doesn't delete the release. At least it didn't work that way for me.

Comment: And sometimes you want to keep the tag and just delete the release. This is the case when undoing a release attached to a tag in a mistake.

Comment: this did work for me, and if you want to keep the tag, you can add it back again afterwards (just keep an eye on the commit sha before you delete)

Comment: This did not work for me. It just deleted the tag, not the release.

Comment: Deleting the tag worked for me _only if done in the web UI_.  Deleting the tag locally and pushing, that did not work to delete the release.

Answer (score 17):

By now  you can delete releases properly using the API:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#delete-a-release

Comment: Awesome. Only thing is you'll have to generate a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: One more tip on forming the address for the curl launch. `curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: [token]" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[projectID]/releases/[tag release]"` worked for me. For [token] see Roshana's comment. For [projectID] see the project splash page, say `https://gitlab.com/[repo]/[project]`, at the top under its name. In the link provided by TheWolfNL, the example `curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: gDybLx3yrUK_HLp3qPjS" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/24/releases/v0.1"` has an incorrect URL **gitlab.example.com**; use **gitlab.com**.

Comment: This awnser was like simple plug an play. Okay I needed to learn fast the use of the gitlab API. But I call it another usefull tool in my hand.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm late but I've created a chrome extension that allows you to do just that, hope it helps :)
https://github.com/tuanddd/grru

Answer (score 3):

Go to Repository -> Tags on the left side Collapse sidebar. Then click on the delete icon on the right of the tag name.

**Example:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#releases-usability-improvements) (August 2022) should improve release management:

> ### Releases usability improvements
>
> In 15.3, we made several improvements that made GitLab Releases easier to use.
>
> Users can now:
>
> - [delete a release directly in the UI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/39471),
> - [set the release date in the UI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/208948),
> - [edit the `release_at` date in the UI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/39471), and
> - [easily identify a historical release](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/199429).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/213862), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/208948), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/199429) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/39471).

For instance: [Delete a release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/#delete-a-release), starting with GitLab 15.2:

> When you delete a release, its assets are also deleted. However, the associated Git tag is not deleted.
>
> ### Prerequisites:
>
> You must have at least the Developer role. Read more about Release permissions.
>
> ### To delete a release in the UI:
>
> - On the top bar, select **Menu > Projects** and find your project.
> - On the left sidebar, select **Deployments > Releases**.
> - In the top-right corner of the release you want to delete, select **Edit this release** ([image: pencil]).
> - On the **Edit Release** page, select **Delete**.
> - Select **Delete release**

Answer (score 0):

## [`gitlab-scripts`](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/gitlab-scripts) repo

I created a bash script that will remove all releases given a repo name,

- [`purge/releases.sh`](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/gitlab-scripts/blob/main/purge/releases.sh)

There are similarly named `purge/tags.sh` and `purge/packages.sh` in the repo. You can call any of them like this,

```
GITLAB_TOKEN="mytoken" ./reset-repo.sh <repo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [gitlab](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gitlab/Gitlab%2FClient%2FProjectReleases:delete_project_release) gem.

```bash
gem install gitlab
gitlab delete_project_release 1234 'v1.2.3'
```