# Change the tag of a release in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, release

I needed to rename tags in a gitlab repo by

```
git tag new old
git tag -d old
git push origin new :old
```

but now I stuck with releases, which are linked to the old tags. Is the only solution to create new Releases and delete the old one like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418978/remove-releases-in-gitlab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only solution to create new Releases and delete the old one

Possibly, because the idea of a release is to be reproductible from an *immutable* tag.

If a tag is mutated (here, renamed), a new release should be done (even though the tag references the same code).

[GitLab 15.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/09/22/gitlab-15-4-released/#add-associated-release-link-to-single-tag-page) (September 2022) illustrates that relation with:

> ### Add associated release link to single tag page
>
> In this update, you can now see the associated release when viewing a specific tag’s information page. This allows you to easily know if a release has been created based on that specific tag and to navigate to the release.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_4/release-show-release-in-tag-page.png -- Add associated release link to single tag page]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/350668).